# Apply checkpoint, replace "Now" in Hyper-V Manager

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

I've created a VM and created a production checkpoint. I've performed various changes on the VM and I now want to revert back to the checkpoint. I right-clicked on the checkpoint and selected "Apply", then in the dialog again selected "Apply" because I don't need a checkpoint of the current state. Everything went fine, however, I still have (of course) the following checkpoint tree:

```
Automatic Checkpoint
|- MyNamedCheckpoint
   |- Now
```

After applying the checkpoint, I'm unsure whether I can delete the MyNamedCheckpoint safely. It says it will merge the checkpoint - what exactly does that mean? Is the Automatic Checkpoint changed? Is Now changed? Why is there still a "Now"? Is "Now" the same as MyNamedCheckpoint now? Is it still the "old" Now after I made the VM changes? Does it change when I start the VM the first time after applying the checkpoint?

Please help me, I'm a bit lost :-)

Comment: `-Now` is the current state of the VM, while `MyNamedCheckpoint` is the save state of the VM, I am 95% certain that deleting the ``MyNamedCheckpoint` would merge the changes.  If you want to purge those changes you would revert the changes THEN delete the checkpoint. I would of course perform some test before I did this for real

Comment: Thank you, I was actually hoping to not have to do such manual testing and get an answer here, maybe with a link to the documentation which I couldn't find. I only found https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints which is not answering my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is very confusing here, as it doesn't specify the *direction*
of the merge.
You will find more information in the article
[How to Create and Delete Checkpoints](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/how-to-create-and-delete-checkpoints-snapshots/).

The `now` is only a pointer to the current state of the VM,
and may move when you apply checkpoints.

The article demonstrates a complex checkpoint architecture:

[image]

Applying the "AV Installed" checkpoint of the "Accounting" checkpoint
branch gives the following result:

[image]

You can see that `now` is on the level as the "AV Installed" checkpoint.

If you delete the checkpoint "Before Update", you will keep the checkpoint
"After Update". The data of "Before Update" will be merged into
"After Update", as it was its base checkpoint.
The `now` still points to the "AV Installed" checkpoint.

[image]